# pyodbc: getting non-ASCII column names

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a weird problem. I have to interact with a third-party database, and some genius used for column name the word `Português`, as is, with the special character.

I use pyodbc to interact with the DB, and normally after querying I fetch each row as a dictionary by doing the following:

```
columns = [desc[0] for desc in self._cursor.description]

for row in self._cursor:
    yield dict(itertools.izip(columns, row))
```

But when I query on this wonderful table, I get a dictionary that looks like follows:

```
{'Portugu\xeas': 'ola'}
```

If I print the key, I get `PortuguÛs`. The key itself is a string that looks like unicode literal (`u'Portugu\xeas' == u'Português'`), so I hacked around my initial function to do this:

```
for row in self._cursor:
    yield {key.decode('unicode-escape'): value for key, value in itertools.izip(columns, row)}
```

Which seems to work fine in my current conditions... but to be honest, I don't really know what I am doing, and I am afraid to put this on production.

Note: I am testing this against a MS SQL Server, but it should run in Oracle as well.

**Is this the right way to handle this?**

Comment: yeah got the same issue, i have been looking at stack overflow. I am still looking for the solution.